# I need a handy jQuery tool (plugin) to work with the map

Tags: jquery, dictionary, canvas, imagemap

I need a handy jQuery tool (plugin) to work with the map.

The project has narisovanaya map with cities marked on it, the possible routes.

Example

[image]

I want to:

- To apply the route (in this example it is shown in green) on top of the map (img)
- Display a small div with information about city

Now inclined to think that would work to implement the map through the canvas, but is not sure whether it is convenient to display the div with information about the city.

Maybe someone encountered a similar problem and help me avoid mistakes.

Comment: Hi @Shaliko, please go to your profile and accept some answers.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to use a Canvas. jQuery can't provide much help in this instance. I suppose you could use jQuery to absolutely position divs over the routes and nodes, but that would be a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently had a similar concept. I decided that the best way to show routes on maps was to Hook into the Google Maps API. This is a complex system and will take a great deal of reading, learning and trying to get it right, but it gives your users full control over the map, allowing them to zoom, move, and calculate routes. You can even put placemarkers on the map.